# SQL Selecting first unique entry for a day based on the date from DateTime field and not time

Tags: sql, datetime, unique

I have a database that handles students clocking in. So each student who appears in the database SHOULD only have 1 entry per day... But people are being stupid so I need to counter it. I am using PHP to pull the query from an SQL Server 2005 database

Table: TAData

```
UserID,DateTime,DeviceID

11111,2014/01/23 07:39:03 AM,1
22222,2014/01/23 07:45:23 AM,2
33333,2014/01/23 07:51:03 AM,1
22222,2014/01/23 08:58:53 AM,3
11111,2014/01/23 09:22:34 AM,1
11111,2014/01/23 11:15:00 AM,5

11111,2014/01/24 07:49:03 AM,1
22222,2014/01/24 07:55:23 AM,2
33333,2014/01/24 08:01:03 AM,1
22222,2014/01/24 08:58:53 AM,3
11111,2014/01/24 09:22:34 AM,1
11111,2014/01/24 11:15:00 AM,5
```

How do I pull a COUNT of the number of days a student arrived late but only count the first entry for the day so I get:

11111 - 1
Because it ignores all entries on day 1 after first one which was early and day 2 had first entry late.
22222 - 2
First entry on both days was late
33333 - 2
First entry on both days was late

```
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*)
    FROM 
        TAData
    WHERE
        UserID = '" . $row["UserID"] . "'
        AND DateTime > '2014-01-15'
        AND CONVERT(varchar,DateTime,108) > '07:45'
```

That is what I have so far and it is counting the number of times a student is late for students like 33333 but it is adding extra entries for people that clock in multiple times a day. So 11111 is getting a count of 5 and not 1.

I have tried:

```
    SELECT 
        CONVERT(varchar,DateTime,103), COUNT(*)
    FROM 
        TAData
    WHERE
        UserID = '" . $row["UserID"] . "'
        AND DateTime > '2014-01-15'
        AND CONVERT(varchar,DateTime,108) BETWEEN '07:45' AND '09:45'
    GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar,DateTime,103)
```

But it returns nonsense to me ("Array ( [0] => 1 [] => 16/01/2014 [1] => 16/01/2014 )")

I have also tried to use DISTINCT but gave up on that because apparently it is not what I want to use.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could already work with what you got. You got your count of 1 in your result array at index 0.

Comment: Except it is supposed to be 7... not 1. So it is not counting properly. It is actually counting only 1 for ALL entries in my query...

Comment: When you say SQLExpress, do you mean SQL Server Express, or some other database product?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2005, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is this, assuming you want a per-user count (otherwise, remove `UserID` from the final select and the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
declare @TAData table (UserID int not null,[DateTime] datetime not null,
                       DeviceID int not null)
insert into @TAData(UserID,[DateTime],DeviceID) values
(11111,'2010-11-04T07:39:03',1),(22222,'2010-11-04T07:45:23',2),
(33333,'2010-11-04T07:51:03',1),(22222,'2010-11-04T08:58:53',3),
(11111,'2010-11-04T09:22:34',1),(11111,'2010-11-04T14:15:00',5),
(11111,'2010-11-05T07:49:03',1),(22222,'2010-11-05T07:55:23',2),
(33333,'2010-11-05T08:01:03',1),(22222,'2010-11-05T08:58:53',3),
(11111,'2010-11-05T09:22:34',1),(11111,'2010-11-05T14:15:00',5)

;With Ordered as (
    select *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY UserID,
                DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,[DateTime]),0)
            ORDER BY [DateTime]) as rn
    from @TAData
), Earliest as (
    select *,
        DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,[DateTime],'19000101'),[DateTime]) as FixedDate
    from Ordered where rn = 1
)
select
    UserID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN FixedDate > '1900-01-01T07:45:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Late
from
    Earliest
group by
    UserID
```

Hopefully, you can see the logic that I've used to create the two `CTE`s. `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` is used in the first CTE (`Ordered`) to normalize the `[DateTime]` values to midnight on their respective day. I prefer this over any form of string conversion in your attempts.

In `Earliest` we again use a `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` pair, this time to normalize the values to be at the same time of day but on a fixed day (01/01/1900). This allows the final `CASE` expression to compare against a single fixed value.

The result:

```
UserID      Late
----------- -----------
11111       1
22222       2
33333       2
```

(I also had to fix your sample data by adjusting the date for the second six set of records to a different day. I also interpreted the hours as 24-hour, despite the presence of `AM`, since I have no idea what `14:15 AM` would be)

---

More explanation:

This is what the `Ordered` [Common Table Expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) produces:

```
UserID      DateTime                DeviceID    rn
----------- ----------------------- ----------- --------------------
11111       2010-11-04 07:39:03.000 1           1
11111       2010-11-04 09:22:34.000 1           2
11111       2010-11-04 14:15:00.000 5           3
11111       2010-11-05 07:49:03.000 1           1
11111       2010-11-05 09:22:34.000 1           2
11111       2010-11-05 14:15:00.000 5           3
22222       2010-11-04 07:45:23.000 2           1
22222       2010-11-04 08:58:53.000 3           2
22222       2010-11-05 07:55:23.000 2           1
22222       2010-11-05 08:58:53.000 3           2
33333       2010-11-04 07:51:03.000 1           1
33333       2010-11-05 08:01:03.000 1           1
```

That is, for each user, for each day, it assigns a distinct [row number](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to each row, where row number 1 is assigned to the earliest event on that day.

This is what `Earliest` produces:

```
UserID      DateTime                DeviceID    rn         FixedDate
----------- ----------------------- ----------- ---------- -----------------------
11111       2010-11-04 07:39:03.000 1           1          1900-01-01 07:39:03.000
11111       2010-11-05 07:49:03.000 1           1          1900-01-01 07:49:03.000
22222       2010-11-04 07:45:23.000 2           1          1900-01-01 07:45:23.000
22222       2010-11-05 07:55:23.000 2           1          1900-01-01 07:55:23.000
33333       2010-11-04 07:51:03.000 1           1          1900-01-01 07:51:03.000
33333       2010-11-05 08:01:03.000 1           1          1900-01-01 08:01:03.000
```

That is, we're picking the rows from `Ordered` where `rn` is equal to 1 - that is, the earliest event, for each user, for each day. And as I said above, we're using a trick with [`DATEADD`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) and [`DATEDIFF`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) to produce a value in `FixedDate` that has the same time components as `DateTime`, but all occurring on `01/01/1900`. This make the final comparison in:

```
CASE WHEN FixedDate > '1900-01-01T07:45:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

easy to write - if we didn't do this, then we'd still have to fiddle around to work out whether, on that particular day, the time was before or after `07:45`.

Comment: Yeah... A friend of mine pointed that out to me too...

I really did not expect the coding to be so complicated. It looks like a hell of a lot to do something so simple. Going to take me a while to figure out what you have done because I am not THAT familiar with SQL queries yet

Comment: @Demonwolf - one of the reasons I do it as a complete query, and with the CTEs is so that you can put it in a query window and examine the individual pieces. E.g. instead of the final `select` at the end, you can do `select * from Ordered` or `select * from Earliest` to see how each of those is working.

Comment: @Demonwolf - I've tried adding a bit more explanation at the bottom of my answer. If things are still unclear, feel free to point out which bits are confusing and I'll try to add more.

Comment: That explanation helped a lot. Thanks. I now see how it all fits together. Still seems very complicated and long but what works, works. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @Demonwolf - it could be simpler and more obvious if you were on 2008, because we can convert the `DateTime` column to just a `date` or just a `time` at the appropriate points, rather than having to use the `DATEADD` tricks.